# getting the last 9 digits of a char buffer in Arduino

Tags: string, arduino, charat

In a previous code of mine, I was using the following line of code to get the last 9digits of the "command" string

```
if(command.indexOf("kitchen light: set top color") >=0) 
{OnColorValueRed = (command.charAt(28)- 48)*100 + (command.charAt(29)- 48)*10 + (command.charAt(30)- 48);}
```

Now i am using a char buffer (char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE];) and using the above code does not work since packetBuffer is not a string, how could I please go about this

Comment: Doesn't simple subscripting like `packetBuffer[28]` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining a function to search the string

```
int indexOf_for_char(const char *str, int str_length, const char *target) {
    // naive method
    for (int index = 0; index < str_length; index++) {
        int j;
        // check if matched
        for (j = 0; target[j] != '\0' && index + j < str_length && str[index + j] == target[j]; j++);
        // if matched, return the index
        if (target[j] == '\0') return index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and using subscripting.

```
if(indexOf_for_char(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE, "kitchen light: set top color") >=0) 
{OnColorValueRed = (packetBuffer[28]- 48)*100 + (packetBuffer[29]- 48)*10 + (packetBuffer[30]- 48);}
```